# UWSGI implement hsts on Heroku

Tags: http, heroku, routes, uwsgi, hsts

I've followed one of uwsgi's snippets to try to enable hsts. Here's my current configuration:

```
[uwsgi]
http-socket = :$(PORT)
master = true
processes = 4
die-on-term = true
module = webapp:app
memory-report = true
check-static = %v/webapp/static/
route= ^/?$ static:%v/webapp/static/pages/index.html

route-host = ^localhost:(?:[0-9]+)$ last:
route-if-not = equal:${HTTPS};on redirect-permanent:https://${HTTP_HOST}${REQUEST_URI}
route-if = equal:${HTTPS};on addheader:Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
route = .* last:
```

What I'm trying to do is enforce hsts for anything except localhost. The site works on localhost, but on heroku, requests to the home page don't get redirected at all, and requests to static assets get into an infinite loop where even https requests get redirected.

## EDIT

The problem is that Heroku's load balancer doesn't connect securely to the dyno. Is there a way to route based on the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header, or based on the complete request url including protocol (so I could match it to `^https:`)?

Comment: Thx for your comment @roberto. I just figured out the exact same answer, but if you want to leave this comment as an answer, I'll accept it so you'll get credit for it.

Comment: What was the answer? Have the exact same problem as you, but I'm not seeing it!

Comment: @joerick your answer worked for me. You could always create a debug method in your web app that prints `os.environ`, so you can see if any other header gives you the info you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
route-if = equal:${HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO};http redirect-permanent:https://${HTTP_HOST}${REQUEST_URI}
```